# Insert into Nth position from the head of the stack

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to fix a problem I'm having with my `insertIntoS` function.  I am trying to insert a value into the linked list or stack from the head point of the stack.  However, I do this and it crashes.  It works when I do it from the top point and I feel like it's because the head point is pointing to NULL. Is this my problem? How would I fix this to be able to insert to the nth position from the head?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct elem {
    int data;
    struct elem *next;
} Element;

Node *top = NULL;
Node *head = NULL;
Element *rear = NULL;
Element *front = NULL;
void pop();
void display();
void push (int num);
void dequeue();
void displayQ();
void insertIntoS(int data, int index);
void insertIntoQ(int data, int index);
void enqueue(int num);

int main(){
    int choice, num, index;

    while(1) {
        printf("\n 1 - Push");
        printf("\n 2 - Pop");
        printf("\n 3 - display stack");
        printf("\n 4 - Enqueue");
        printf("\n 5 - Dequeue ");
        printf("\n 6 - Show Queue ");
        printf("\n 7 - Insert Into Queue ");
        printf("\n 8 - Insert Into Stack ");
        printf("\n 9 - Exit ");
        printf("\n Please enter your choice");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter Data : ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                push(num);
                break;
            case 2:
                pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                enqueue(num);
                break;
            case 5:
                dequeue();
                break;
            case 6:
                displayQ();
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                printf("Enter the index: ");
                scanf("%d", &index);
                insertIntoQ(num, index);
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                printf("Enter the index: ");
                scanf("%d", &index);
                insertIntoS(num, index);
                break;
            case 9:
                exit(0);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void push (int num){
    Node *temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Stack OVERFLOW");
        return;
    }

    if(head == NULL) {
         temp->data = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head = temp;
        printf("Value of the head after push : %d \n", head->data);
    }
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;
}

void pop(){
    Node *temp;
    if(top == NULL){
        printf("You are trying to pop from a stack that is empty");
        return;
    }
    temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
}

void display(){
    Node *p;
    if(top == NULL){
        printf("Empty Stack");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n Stack : \n");
    p=top;
    while(p != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
}

void displayQ(){
    Element *p = front;
    if(p == NULL){
        printf("Empty stack\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("Queue: \n");
        while(p != NULL){
            printf("%d\n", p->data);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
}

void dequeue(){
    Element *temp = front;
    if(front == NULL){
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return;
    }
    if(front == rear){
        front = rear = temp;
    }else{
        front = front->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}

void enqueue(int num){
    Element *temp = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Stack OVERFLOW");
        return;
    }
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = temp;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
    printf("value of rear in enque: %d\n", rear->data);
}

void insertIntoQ(int data, int index){
    int i;
    Element *temp = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(index == 1){
        temp->next = rear;
        rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    Element *temp1 = rear;
    for(i = 0; i<index;i++){
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp1;
}

void insertIntoS(int data, int index){
    int i;
    Node *temp1 = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if(index == 1){
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }

    printf("Value of head in insert %d\n", head->data);
    Node *temp2 = head;

    for(i = 0; i<index;i++){
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        printf("i count : %d\n", i);
    }
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input that makes the program crash?

Comment: i enter data as follows 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 8 9 3

Comment: If thats unclear ^^ Push 1 push 2 push 3 push 4 push 5 stack looks like 5 4 3 2 1 and then i insert the value 9 at index 3

Comment: @Tyler Pierog It is unclear what is the meaning of head and top? What is the difference between them?

Comment: In the future, please make sure any example code you post is properly indented. It's confusing and harder to spot errors when indentation is all over the place (as it was in a few places, including one or two lines of `insertIntoS`). This should apply to the code you write as well :)

Comment: `Node *temp2 = head;` , `head` has one element. The cause that it is mixed with `top` and `head`.

Comment: @Tyler Pierog And what to do if the index of the inserting value is greater than the number of elements in the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the difference between `top` and `head`? `head` only gets assigned after your first push, so it always points to the bottom (oldest node) of the stack; `top` always points to the top (most recent node) of the stack. This seems kind of silly. `insertIntoS` starts from `head` and tries to go `index` elements forward, but it's already at the end of your stack list... you crash.

It seems like you made two variables `top` and `head` that were supposed to be the same thing, and you used only one or the other in different places so their use and value is inconsistent. Alternatively, you had something in mind that's different for both of them and made a mistake using the two of them.

It seems most likely to me that `head` shouldn't exist and `top` is what you meant to use throughout.

---

In more detail:

I'm assuming that you're entering the sequence "push 1, push 2, push 3, push 4, push 5, insert 9 at index 3".

In `push()`, you assign `head` if and only if it's `NULL`. So, on the **first** push of value `1`, `head` points to Node{.data = 1}. `top` also points to the same Node{.data = 1}.

On the **second** push an onward, `head != NULL` so you skip the if statement. `head` doesn't change, it stays pointing to the bottom of the stack at Node{.data = 1}! But top always points to the newest Node.

So at the end of your pushes, you have:

```
5    4    3    2    1
^                   ^
top                 head
```

Now you call insertIntoS(9, 3).

You start by assigning `temp2 = head`, so now `temp2` points to the bottom of the stack at Node{.data = 1}. In the for loop (i = 0), you assign `temp2 = temp2->next` ... so now `temp2` is `NULL` (because nothing comes after 1).

On the next for loop iteration (i = 1), you try to access `temp2->next` but `temp2` is `NULL`... you try to dereference a null pointer and crash.

`insertIntoS` is supposed to start from the 5 at the beginning of the stack (i.e. `top`), right? This `head` variable seems a bit wonky.

Comment: I had it inserting from the top of the stack before. What you said just helped reinforce why. Thank you for the help it really clears that up :)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you have to write two containers: Stack and Queue.

In fact you could use the same structure Node for the both containers. However in the demonstrative program I used two diferent structures for nodes of the Stack and nodes of the Queue and encapsulated these structures in structure Stack and structure Queue.

Taking as a template the implementation of the Stack you will need to write the implementation of the Queue yourself.

Here is the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Stack
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
    } *top;
} stack;

void push ( int data )
{
    struct Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = stack.top;
    stack.top = tmp;

    printf( "Value on the top of the stack after push: %d \n", stack.top->data );
}    

void pop()
{
    if ( stack.top == NULL )
    {        
        printf( "You are trying to pop from a stack that is empty" );
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node *tmp = stack.top;
        stack.top = stack.top->next;
        printf( "The popped value from the stack: %d \n",  tmp->data );
        free( tmp );
    }
}    

_Bool is_stack_empty()
{
    return stack.top == NULL;
}

void clear_stack()
{
    while ( stack.top != NULL )
    {
        struct Node *tmp = stack.top;
        stack.top = stack.top->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

void insert_into_stack( int data, size_t index )
{
    struct Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    tmp->data = data;

    struct Node *after = NULL, *before = stack.top;
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; before != NULL && i < index; i++ )
    {
        after = before;
        before = before->next;
    } 

    tmp->next = before;
    if ( after == NULL )
    {
        stack.top = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        after->next = tmp;
    }        

    printf( "Value %d is inserted at position %zu\n", tmp->data, i );
}    

void display_stack()
{
    if ( is_stack_empty() )
    {
        puts( "Stack is empty" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\nStack:" );
        for ( struct Node *tmp = stack.top; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next )
        {
            printf( " %d", tmp->data );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

struct Queue
{
    struct Elem
    {
        int data;
        struct Elem *next;
    } *head, *tail;
} queue;

int main( void )
{
    int choice;

    do 
    {
        printf("\n  1 - Push");
        printf("\n  2 - Pop");
        printf("\n  3 - Insert Into Stack ");
        printf("\n  4 - Display Stack");
        printf("\n  5 - clear Stack");
        printf("\n  6 - Enqueue");
        printf("\n  7 - Dequeue ");
        printf("\n  8 - Insert Into Queue ");
        printf("\n  9 - Display Queue ");
        printf("\n 10 - Display Queue ");
        printf("\n 11 - Clear Queue ");
        printf("\n  0 - Exit ");
        printf("\n\n Please enter your choice: ");

        choice = 0;                  
        scanf( "%d", &choice );

        switch ( choice ) 
        {
            case 1:
            {
                int data = 0;
                printf("Enter Data : ");
                scanf( "%d", &data );
                push( data );
                break;
            }                
            case 2:
            {                
                pop();
                break;
            }                
            case 3:
            {
                int data = 0;
                printf("Enter Data : ");
                scanf( "%d", &data );
                size_t index = 0;
                printf( "Enter the index: " );
                scanf( "%zu", &index );
                insert_into_stack( data, index );
                break;
            }                
            case 4:
            {                
                display_stack();
                break;
            }                
            case 5:
            {                
                clear_stack();
                break;
            }                
            case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10:
            {                
                puts( "\nWrite it yourself\n" );
                break;
            }                
            default:
            {
                if ( choice != 0 ) 
                {                   
                    puts( "\nInvalid input. Try again.\n" );
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( !is_stack_empty() ) clear_stack();
                    //if ( !is_queue_empty() ) clear_queue();
                }                    
                break;
            }
        }                
    } while ( choice != 0 );                
}
```

It might have the following output

```
  1 - Push
  2 - Pop
  3 - Insert Into Stack 
  4 - Display Stack
  5 - clear Stack
  6 - Enqueue
  7 - Dequeue 
  8 - Insert Into Queue 
  9 - Display Queue 
 10 - Display Queue 
 11 - Clear Queue 
  0 - Exit 

 Please enter your choice: 1
 Enter Data : 1
 Value on the top of the stack after push: 1 

  1 - Push
  2 - Pop
  3 - Insert Into Stack 
  4 - Display Stack
  5 - clear Stack
  6 - Enqueue
  7 - Dequeue 
  8 - Insert Into Queue 
  9 - Display Queue 
 10 - Display Queue 
 11 - Clear Queue 
  0 - Exit 

 Please enter your choice: 1
 Enter Data : 2
 Value on the top of the stack after push: 2 

  1 - Push
  2 - Pop
  3 - Insert Into Stack 
  4 - Display Stack
  5 - clear Stack
  6 - Enqueue
  7 - Dequeue 
  8 - Insert Into Queue 
  9 - Display Queue 
 10 - Display Queue 
 11 - Clear Queue 
  0 - Exit 

 Please enter your choice: 4
 Stack: 2 1

  1 - Push
  2 - Pop
  3 - Insert Into Stack 
  4 - Display Stack
  5 - clear Stack
  6 - Enqueue
  7 - Dequeue 
  8 - Insert Into Queue 
  9 - Display Queue 
 10 - Display Queue 
 11 - Clear Queue 
  0 - Exit 

 Please enter your choice: 3
 Enter Data : 3
 Enter the index: 1
 Value 3 is inserted at position 1

  1 - Push
  2 - Pop
  3 - Insert Into Stack 
  4 - Display Stack
  5 - clear Stack
  6 - Enqueue
  7 - Dequeue 
  8 - Insert Into Queue 
  9 - Display Queue 
 10 - Display Queue 
 11 - Clear Queue 
  0 - Exit 

 Please enter your choice: 4
 Stack: 2 3 1

  1 - Push
  2 - Pop
  3 - Insert Into Stack 
  4 - Display Stack
  5 - clear Stack
  6 - Enqueue
  7 - Dequeue 
  8 - Insert Into Queue 
  9 - Display Queue 
 10 - Display Queue 
 11 - Clear Queue 
  0 - Exit 

 Please enter your choice: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code

```
1) compiles cleanly, 
2) contains several comments indicating probable problem areas
3) checks for errors in system calls (I.E. malloc)
```

The posted code is trying to create/manipulate a circular queue 
and trying to create/manipulate a linked list

There are logic errors in both activities and I'm not real sure which activity contains the problem you found.

The posted code (and this code) fails to pass all malloc'd memory to free() before exiting the program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct elem {
    int data;
    struct elem *next;
} Element;

Node *top = NULL;
Node *head = NULL;

Element *rear = NULL;
Element *front = NULL;

void pop( void );
void display( void );
void push (int num);
void dequeue( void );
void displayQ( void );
void insertIntoS(int data, int index);
void insertIntoQ(int data, int index);
void enqueue(int num);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    int num;
    int index;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n 1 - Push");
        printf("\n 2 - Pop");
        printf("\n 3 - display stack");
        printf("\n 4 - Enqueue");
        printf("\n 5 - Dequeue ");
        printf("\n 6 - Show Queue ");
        printf("\n 7 - Insert Into Queue ");
        printf("\n 8 - Insert Into Stack ");
        printf("\n 9 - Exit ");
        printf("\n Please enter your choice");

        if( 1 != scanf("%d",&choice) )
        { // then scanf failed
            perror( "scanf for menu choice failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // immplied else, scanf successful

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter Data : ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                push(num);
                break;

            case 2:
                pop();
                break;

            case 3:
                display();
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                enqueue(num);
                break;

            case 5:
                dequeue();
                break;

            case 6:
                displayQ();
                break;

            case 7:
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                printf("Enter the index: ");
                scanf("%d", &index);
                insertIntoQ(num, index);
                break;

            case 8:
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                printf("Enter the index: ");
                scanf("%d", &index);
                insertIntoS(num, index);
                break;

            case 9:
                exit(0);

            default:
                printf( "invalid value entered, valid values 0...9\n");
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end while
} // end function: main


void push (int num)
{
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        perror( "malloc for new stack node failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if(NULL == head )
    {
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head = temp;
        printf("Value of the head after push : %d \n", head->data);
    }

    else
    {
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = top;
        top = temp;
    }
} // end function: push


void pop()
{
    Node *temp;
    if(NULL == top)
    {
        printf("You are trying to pop from a stack that is empty");
        return;
    }

    temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
} // end function: pop


void display()
{
    Node *p;

    if(top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Stack");
        return;
    }

    printf("\n Stack : \n");
    p=top;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
} // end function: display


void displayQ()
{
    Element *p = front;

    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty stack\n");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Queue: \n");

        while(p != NULL){
            printf("%d\n", p->data);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
} // end function: displayQ


void dequeue()
{
    Element *temp = front;

    if(NULL == front)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return;
    }

    // nonsence code block
    if(front == rear)
    {
        front = rear = temp;
    }

    else
    {
        front = front->next;
    }

    free(temp);
} // end funtion: dequeue


void enqueue(int num)
{
    Element *temp = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if(NULL == temp )
    {
        perror( "malloc for new element failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = temp;
    }

    else
    {
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;  // probably incorrect
    }

    printf("value of rear in enque: %d\n", rear->data);
} // end function: enqaueue


void insertIntoQ(int data, int index)
{
    int i;
    Element *temp = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if( NULL == temp)
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for new Element failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    // probably incorrect
    if(index == 1){
        temp->next = rear;
        rear = temp;
        return;
    }

    Element *temp1 = rear;
    for(i = 0; i<index;i++)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    temp->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp1; // probably should be: templ->next = temp;
}

void insertIntoS(int data, int index)
{
    int i;
    Node *temp1 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if( NULL == temp1)
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for new Node failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    // probably incorrect as loses all other nodes
    if(index == 1)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }

    printf("Value of head in insert %d\n", head->data);
    Node *temp2 = head;

    for(i = 0; i<index;i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        printf("i count : %d\n", i);
    }

    // following 2 lines probably incorrect
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
} // end function: insertIntoS
```

Comment: Strongly suggest using a debugger to step through your code so you can see exactly what is going wrong.